# MongoDB PHPH driver with PECL not working

Tags: php, mongodb, lampp

I am on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am have been using LAMPP, I tried to install MongoDB driver with **PECL**, got it installed added this line "extension=mongodb.so" in php.ini ==> **/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini**
I have restarted LAMPP many times but Mongodb won't appear in phpinfo(); page.

**PHP Version 5.6.24
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3**

I have had setup the project,It throws me this error,

**Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /home/udesk/workspaces/platinum-nyc/web/app/themes/Platinum/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 81**